# Show that this sequence converges to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{n} n^{0.5} 
$$

I tried using the 'Sandwich Theorem' but cannot seem to find a larger sequence for this.

Edit : Apologies I forgot to specify that |x| < 1.

Comment: Without any restriction on $x$? Sure about that?

Comment: You call "series" what most of us would call "a function" or even a sequence. Is really $\;x\to\infty\;$ or should it be $\;n\to\infty\;$ ? Either way you must explain what is each thing there.

Comment: I have made some changes, thanks.

Comment: generalize the problem to real n and use L'Hopital I'd say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion on my comment: [L'Hopital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is a fabulous tool since you can deal with most sequences that way. So here is how that works:
$$
f(n)=x^{-n}, g(n)=n^{0.5} \implies x^nn^{0.5}=\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\to \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g'(n)}{f'(n)}
$$
where $f'(n)=-\ln(x)x^{-n},\ g'(n)=0.5 n^{-0.5}$ implies
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g'(n)}{f'(n)}=\frac{1}{-0.5\ln(x)}\frac{x^n}{n^{0.5}}=0$$

You need $x>0$, but you can assume that without loss of generality, otherwise do it for $|x|$ and argue that:
$$|x^nn^{0.5} -0|=|x|^nn^{0.5}\to 0$$

Comment: oh ok thank you! we are not allowed to use L'hospital for my homework, but this is enlightening. I hope we are taught this soon.

Comment: It is a bit overkill, but it works for a lot of things so you tend to try it first if you can write it as functions and it almost always works. I actually didn't try it when I commented and just gave it a shot later. And in order to show L'Hopital you of course need other arguments, so it makes sense that you learn those first.

Answer (score 2):

Note that$$\frac{(n+1)^{1/2}\lvert x\rvert^{n+1}}{n^{1/2}\lvert x\rvert^n}=\sqrt{1+\frac1n}\lvert x\rvert.$$Since $\lvert x\rvert<1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}=\sqrt{1+\frac1n}\lvert x\rvert=\lvert x\rvert<1$. So, take some $r\in\bigl(\lvert x\rvert,1\bigr)$. For some $N\in\mathbb N$, you have$$n\geqslant N\implies\frac{(n+1)^{1/2}x^{n+1}}{n^{1/2}x^n}<r.$$But then$$n\geqslant N\implies n^{1/2}\lvert x\rvert\leqslant N^{1/2}\lvert x\rvert r^{n-N}.$$Now, use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}N^{1/2}\lvert x\rvert r^{n-N}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=x^nn^{1/2}$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=x(1+\frac1n)^{1/2}$.

Since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac1n)^{1/2}=1$, there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that, when $n>N$, then $(1+\frac1n)^{1/2}<\varepsilon$ for some fixed $\varepsilon<1/|x|$.

Thus, when $n>N$, then $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}<|x|\varepsilon<1$. This shows that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!

Comment: how do I get that <1/|| ?

Comment: Since $|x|<1$, we see $1<1/|x|$, so there exists some $\varepsilon$ such that $1<\varepsilon<1/|x|$.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute ratio of two consecutive terms $n+1$ and $n$ is

$$|x|\sqrt{1+\frac1n}.$$

For any $|x|$, you will find an $n$ such that this ratio is smaller than $1$ (take $n>\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2}$), and from there the sequence is bounded above by a geometric sequence that converges to $0$.

Comment: thank you, this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let’s wlog assume $x>0$. Call the sequence whose limit we’re trying to evaluate $s_n$. I claim the sequence has a decreasing tail. For if one chooses $N$ so big that
$$x^2 < \frac{N}{N+1}$$
then one sees quite easily that $s_{N+1} < s_N$.
The sequence is clearly bounded below by $0$, so it has a limit, call it $L$. Now we have the sequence
$$x \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} s_n =s_{n+1}$$
converges to $L$ as well. But it also must converge to $xL$, so $xL=L$, so if $L \neq 0$, $x=1$. It follows $L=0$.

**edit** This idea is based on my favorite proof that $x^n$ goes to 0 as $n$ goes to infinity if $0<x<1$. Namely, it is clear this sequence decreases, but if you multiply the sequence by $x$ it shifts, while the limit then should get strictly smaller if it were not $0$.